# Mover arquivos entre pastas com C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação que verifica e baixa um arquivo assim que executada através do `Window_Loaded`.

Aqui está o método que realiza essa tarefa:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.meusite.com.br/dirdaaplicacao/arquivoXML.xml");

        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
        XmlNode node1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/ZipFile");
        string version = node.InnerText;
        string zipfile = node1.InnerText;
        string End = (@"\\servidor\wwwroot\meusite.com.br\dirdaaplicacao\");
        string file = (End + zipfile);
        string versionAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        if (Convert.ToDouble(version) <= Convert.ToDouble(versionAssembly))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sistema Atualizado " + version);
        }
        else
        {
            ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(file);
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
                {
                    zipEntry.Extract(@"C:\IASD\Diretorio\Temp", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Atualizando o sistema! A aplicação será reiniciada! Versão: " + version);
```

O executavel e os arquivos de instalação dessa aplicação ficam em `c:\IASD\Diretorio` e os arquivos que são descompactados ficarão em `c:\IASD\Diretorio\Temp`.

Criei a pasta Temp porque não é possível baixar para o diretório da aplicação um arquivo que está sendo utilizado (como por exemplo o próprio .exe da aplicação) mesmo utilizando a API Ionic.zip.

```
zipEntry.Extract(@"C:\IASD\Diretorio", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
```

O erro que é reportado refere-se  a `The file 'nome_do_arquivo' already exists.`

Então gostaria de uma ajuda para esse problema:

No final da extração para a pasta Temp chamo um comando em DOS que fecha a aplicação, move os arquivos da pasta `c:\IASD\Diretorio\Temp` para a pasta `c:\IASD\Diretorio` e reinicia a aplicação.

Obs.: Testei o método acima rodando diretamente do Visual Studio e ele funcionou perfeitamente.

Se puderem ajudar com esses comando em DOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O .Net possui um método específico para mover arquivos:

```
System.IO.File.Move("c:\\origem.txt", "c:\\diretorio\\destino.txt");
```

Note que esse método é capaz de mover e também de renomear o arquivo... para mover apenas, indique o mesmo nome de arquivo:

```
System.IO.File.Move("c:\\origem.txt", "c:\\diretorio\\origem.txt");
```

**EDIT** Acho que entendi o que você quer fazer:

Se você está fazendo um tipo de atualizador automático, eu faria assim:

Você vai ter que fazer duas aplicações então, uma principal, e outra que será o atualizador.

- Na aplicação principal, ao clicar em atualizar, a aplicação principal deve atualizar o atualizador, depois abrir o atualizador e então se fechar.
- O atualizador por sua vez, atualiza a aplicação principal, inicia a aplicação principal e depois se fecha, isso tudo de forma automática.

Comment: Como eu faço para mover um arquivo que está em execução com a aplicação aberta? Pensei em um comando pelo cmd que assim que o arquivo for baixado na pasta temp, ele fecharia a aplicação, copiaria os arquivos e, em seguida, reiniciasse a aplicação.